# Trigger not updating field

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to write a trigger that will update a look up field on the CampaignMemeber when it finds a matching record on Marketing_KPI_Target__c.

The code saves but does not update anything not sure what I am missing.

```
trigger CampaignMemberTrigger on CampaignMember (after insert, after update) {
    // Get a list of fields from the sObject Marketing_KPI_Target__c and name the list kpiTargetList
    List<Marketing_KPI_Target__c> kpiTargetList = [SELECT Type_of_Sale__c, ECI_Product__c, CurrencyIsoCode,KPI_Target_Date__c FROM Marketing_KPI_Target__c];
    List<CampaignMember> cmlis =[SELECT id, Type_of_Sale__c, ECI_Product__c, Currency__c,Response_Tracking_Date__c,HasResponded FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
        for (CampaignMember member : cmlis) {
         for (Marketing_KPI_Target__c kpiTarget : kpiTargetList) {
             if (kpiTarget.Type_of_Sale__c == member.Type_of_Sale__c &&
                kpiTarget.ECI_Product__c == member.ECI_Product__c &&
                kpiTarget.CurrencyIsoCode == member.Currency__c &&
                member.Response_Tracking_date__c != Null &&
                kpiTarget.KPI_Target_Date__c.month() == member.Response_Tracking_Date__c.month() &&
                kpiTarget.KPI_Target_Date__c.year() == member.Response_Tracking_Date__c.year() &&
                member.HasResponded == True
                )
            {
                 member.Marketing_KPI_Target__c = kpiTarget.Id;
                 continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are setting this field on CampaignMember then trigger event should be before insert and before update.

Comment: What @Devendra said. Also you don't need to query the records, just use `Trigger.new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Derek said you need to change your Trigger from `after insert`/`after update` to `before insert`/`before update`.  This will allow you to update the Campaign Member records directly and you won't need to query them.

Replace your SOQL query with `Trigger.new` to get the list of Campaign Members to operate on.

```
trigger CampaignMemberTrigger on CampaignMember (after insert, after update) {
    // Get a list of fields from the sObject Marketing_KPI_Target__c and name the list kpiTargetList
    List<Marketing_KPI_Target__c> kpiTargetList = [SELECT Type_of_Sale__c, ECI_Product__c, CurrencyIsoCode,KPI_Target_Date__c FROM Marketing_KPI_Target__c];
    List<CampaignMember> cmlis =Trigger.new;
        for (CampaignMember member : cmlis) {
         for (Marketing_KPI_Target__c kpiTarget : kpiTargetList) {
             if (kpiTarget.Type_of_Sale__c == member.Type_of_Sale__c &&
                kpiTarget.ECI_Product__c == member.ECI_Product__c &&
                kpiTarget.CurrencyIsoCode == member.Currency__c &&
                member.Response_Tracking_date__c != Null &&
                kpiTarget.KPI_Target_Date__c.month() == member.Response_Tracking_Date__c.month() &&
                kpiTarget.KPI_Target_Date__c.year() == member.Response_Tracking_Date__c.year() &&
                member.HasResponded == True
                )
            {
                 member.Marketing_KPI_Target__c = kpiTarget.Id;
                 continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, when you want to update records of a given sObject in a trigger on the same sObject, you should be running the trigger on a before event like `Before Update`.

This is advice that comes from the [developer docs on Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm). The relevant excerpt being

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - Before triggers are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - After triggers are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.

In a `Before Update` trigger, you won't need to run a DML call like `update <some list of records>;` if you make changes to the record that exists in either the `Trigger.new` or `Trigger.newMap` trigger context variables.

To get your trigger working more along the lines that you expect, I'd do the following:

- Change your trigger to run `Before Insert` and `Before Update`
- Get rid of your query for CampaignMembers, you don't need it
- Change `for (CampaignMember member : cmlis)` to `for (CampaignMember member : Trigger.new)`

Comment: Here is the new code and there is one problem. When adding a new record to the CampainMember object the trigger will not fire even if it meets all the criteria. If I just resave the record the trigger works fine.  Any way around this problem I am not sure where to start.   I changed the For loop to this  ' for (CampaignMember member : Trigger.New) {
    for (Marketing_KPI_Target__c kpiTarget : kpiTargetList) { '

Comment: FYI you can add an authoritative reference to why OP should use `before` triggers [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm).

Comment: @Jeremy How are you testing this? Are you sure that you have some KPI records in place? Are you sure that the `CampaignMembers` that you're inserting or updating match all of the requirements in your trigger?